# how to avoid busy waiting for shared memory reader?

Tags: c++, ipc, shared-memory

I am using shared memory to pass data among several processes.

to synchronize, i allocate a `pthread_mutex_t`.

it worked well, for writer, it just write data into shared memory. no matter how many readers are waiting, they can be waked up then get data correctly.

but the problem is the CPU usage, the busy waiting will make CPU 100% used.

to decrease that, the `sem_post` `sem_wait` and `pthread_cond_t` are not choice, because:
`sem_post` only wake up one reader, it can't wake up all readers.

`pthread_cond_t` will be inconsistent if one reader exit unexpectedly.

So, to wake up all readers and avoid busy waiting, is there any methods?

my busy waiting but worked well code is below:

```
// header.hpp
#pragma once
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <error.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/sysinfo.h>
#include <atomic>
#include <memory>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Header {
  const size_t size_;
  std::atomic_int32_t tail_;
  pthread_cond_t cv_;
  pthread_mutex_t mut_; // , cv_mut_;
  Header(size_t size, int32_t tail) : size_(size), tail_(tail) {
    pthread_mutexattr_t mutexattr;
    pthread_mutexattr_init(&mutexattr);
    pthread_mutexattr_setpshared(&mutexattr, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);
    pthread_mutexattr_setrobust(&mutexattr, PTHREAD_MUTEX_ROBUST);
    pthread_mutex_init(&mut_, &mutexattr); 
    pthread_mutex_init(&cv_mut_, &mutexattr); 

    pthread_condattr_t condattr;
    pthread_condattr_init(&condattr);
    pthread_condattr_setpshared(&condattr, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);
pthread_cond_init(&cv_, &condattr);
  }
};
```

shm_worker.hpp

```
#pragma once
#include "./header.hpp"

class ShmWorker {
 public:
  ShmWorker() {}

  virtual ~ShmWorker() {
    shmdt(m_data);
    shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, 0); 
  }

 protected:
  key_t get_keyid(const std::string & name) {
    const std::string & s = "./" + name;
    if (access(s.c_str(), F_OK) == -1) { const std::string & s1 = "touch " + s; system(s1.c_str()); }
    key_t semkey = ftok(name.c_str(), 1); 
    if (semkey == -1) { printf("shm_file:%s not existed\n", s.c_str()); exit(1); }
    return semkey;
  }

  template <typename T>
  void init(const std::string& name, int size) {
    m_key = get_keyid(name);
    shmid = shmget(m_key, 0, 0); 
    if (shmid == -1) {
      if (errno == ENOENT || errno == EINVAL) {
        shmid = shmget(m_key, sizeof(Header) + sizeof(T) * size, 0666 | IPC_CREAT | O_EXCL);
        if (shmid == -1) { printf("both connet and create are failed for shm\n"); exit(1); }
        printf("creating new shm %s\n", name.c_str());
        // create_new = true;
        m_data = (char*)shmat(shmid, NULL, 0); 
        Header* header = new Header(size, 0); 
        memcpy(m_data, header, sizeof(Header));
      } else {
        printf("init failed\n");
        exit(1);
      }   
    } else {
      m_data = (char*)shmat(shmid, 0, 0); 
      // m_size = reinterpret_cast<std::atomic_int*>(m_data)->load();
    }   

    if (m_data == (char*)(-1)) { perror("shmat"); exit(1); }
  }

  int m_key;
  int shmid;
  char* m_data;
};
```

// shm_sender.hpp

```
#pragma once
#include <mutex>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <fstream>
#include "./shm_worker.hpp"

template <typename T>
class ShmSender: public ShmWorker {
 public:
  ShmSender(const std::string& key, int size = 4096) {
    init <T> (key, size);
    header_ = (Header*)m_data;
  }

  virtual ~ShmSender() = default;

  void Send(const T& shot) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&header_->mut_);
    memcpy(m_data + sizeof(Header) + header_->tail_.load() % header_->size_ * sizeof(T), &shot, sizeof(shot));
    header_->tail_.fetch_add(1);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&header_->mut_);
  }

 private:
  Header * header_;
};
```

// shm_recver.hpp

```
#pragma once
#include <unistd.h>
#include "./shm_worker.hpp"

template <typename T>
class ShmRecver : public ShmWorker {
 public:
  ShmRecver(const std::string & key, int size = 4096) {
    init <T> (key, size);
    header_ = (Header*)m_data;
    read_index = header_->tail_.load();
  }

  virtual ~ShmRecver() {
    printf("shmrecver exit\n");
  }

  void Recv(T& t, const std::string & msg) {
    while (read_index == header_->tail_.load());  // HERE IS THE PROBLEM
    // busy waiting to check tail, worked but caused 100% CPU usage 
    t = *(T*)(m_data + sizeof(Header) + (read_index % header_->size_ * sizeof(T)));
    read_index ++; 
  }

 private:
  int read_index;
  Header* header_;
};
```

and a version using conditional_variable (i think it doesn't work) is here:

// shm_recver with pthread_cond_t wake

```
#pragma once
#include <unistd.h>
#include "./shm_worker.hpp"

template <typename T>
class ShmRecver : public ShmWorker {
 public:
  ShmRecver(const std::string & key, int size = 4096) {
    init <T> (key, size);
    header_ = (Header*)m_data;
    read_index = header_->tail_.load();
  }

  virtual ~ShmRecver() {
    printf("shmrecver exit\n");
  }

  void Recv(T& t, const std::string & msg) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&header_->cv_mut_);
    while (read_index == header_->tail_.load()) pthread_cond_wait(&header_->cv_, &header_->cv_mut_);
    // while (read_index == header_->tail_.load());
    t = *(T*)(m_data + sizeof(Header) + (read_index % header_->size_ * sizeof(T)));
    read_index ++; 
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&header_->cv_mut_);
  }

 private:
  int read_index;
  Header* header_;
};
```

// sender.hpp

```
#pragma once
#include <mutex>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <fstream>
#include "./shm_worker.hpp"

template <typename T>
class ShmSender: public ShmWorker {
 public:
  ShmSender(const std::string& key, int size = 4096) {
    init <T> (key, size);
    header_ = (Header*)m_data;
  }

  virtual ~ShmSender() = default;

  void Send(const T& shot) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&header_->mut_);
    memcpy(m_data + sizeof(Header) + header_->tail_.load() % header_->size_ * sizeof(T), &shot, sizeof(shot));
    header_->tail_.fetch_add(1);
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&header_->cv_);
    // if (ret != 0) { printf("cond broadcast error:%d\n", ret); exit(1); }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&header_->mut_);
  }

 private:
  Header * header_;
};
```

the test code is:

```
// recver.cpp
#include "shm_recver.hpp"
#include <thread>

void run(char * msg) {
  ShmRecver<int> recv("shm_test");
  int a;
  printf("run %s\n", msg);
  while (1) {
    recv.Recv(a, msg);
    printf("%s Recv %d\n", msg, a); 
  }
}

int main() {
  char msg1[12] = "worker1";
  char msg2[12] = "worker2";
  std::thread worker(run, msg1);
  std::thread worker2(run, msg2);

  worker.join();
  worker2.join();
}

// sender.cpp
#include "shm_sender.hpp"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  ShmSender<int> sender("shm_test");
  int a;
  while (std::cin >> a && a != 100) {
    sender.Send(a);
    printf("sent %d\n", a); 
  }
}
```

the expected result is:

when the sender send int, the recver(two threads) will wake up to receive the data.

but with `pthread_cond_t`, it stuck in `pthread_boardcast`

Comment: Are the readers independent programs? Are they forked by your program? Do the new processes execute some other independent program? Is it all inside your own code? If it's all inside your own code, and one of the reader processes "exit unexpectedly" you have a bug that you need to fix anyway, so I don't think that's a valid reason to not use a shared `pthread_cond_t`. If the readers are independent and not controlled by you, then it might be a different matter (though I would consider them "exit unexpectedly" a bug that needs fixing any way).

Comment: Is there another broadcast channel you can use?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude readers are independent, each reader is a single process. I want to build a shared memory which are free to join and free to leave. but one reader leaves will cause p```thread_cond_broadcast``` stuck, that's why i think ```pthread_cond_t``` is not good here

Comment: I would suggest you use the cross platform STD library for concurrency, assuming you have access to C++ 17. The documentation is also easier to understand than the *nix docs.

Comment: Do you want to pass data among *processes* or *threads*?

Comment: You are looking for pthread_cond_t. I didn't understand the problem with pthread_cond_t. However, I am not sure if it works between different processes

Comment: @nothingisme Are you working with threads or processes here? I'm not sure how you are segmenting. If the latter you should almost certainly be using the former.

Comment: I believe you don't understand how to work with condition variables. Yes, they may awaken randomly. So what? You simply add a condition that the code tests if it actually needs to perform a read. This is the most basic knowledge of working with condition variables.

Comment: @nothingisme Is it possible for you to re-write your code as multi threaded rather than multi process? That's going to be much simpler to share memory between.

Comment: @nothingisme And you will be able to signal for all threads to wake quite easily.

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant no, i do need to use them in multi process

Comment: @nothingisme Can you explain why? It might be possible to recommend an alternative way of structuring what you are trying to do?

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant I subscribed stock data from different brokers, and i don't want one broker's data crash affect others. for multi_threads, if one broker's data service crashed, the whole data process crashed

Comment: @nothingisme Did you write the code which causes the crash?